# Proving A is bounded from above iff the integers of A is bounded from above

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Prove/Disprove: $A$ is bounded from above $\iff$ $A\cap\mathbb{Z}$ is bounded from above.

Basically, due to the fact that any finite set (or just finite in positive or negative) is bounded it is true.

$A$ is bounded from above $\rightarrow$ $a\leq x$, 

$z\in A\cap\mathbb{Z}$  $\rightarrow$ $z\in A \wedge z\in \mathbb{Z}$, due to $A$ bounded from above and $A\cap\mathbb{Z}$ is finite $\rightarrow$ $z\leq x$ and $A\cap\mathbb{Z}$ is bounded from above.

$A\cap\mathbb{Z}$ is bounded from above $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{Z}$ is not bounded $\rightarrow$ $A$ is bounded from above.

Is this a valid proof? Can we say in general the every intersection of a bounded set is bounded?

Comment: Integers of $A$ is bounded from above does not imply that $A$ is bounded from above. Let $A=\{\frac{2}{1},\frac{3}{2},\frac{4}{3},...\}$. Integers of $A$ is $\{2\}$, which is bounded from above, whereas $A$ is not.

Comment: On the other hand, if $\{\lfloor a \rfloor \mid a \in A \}$ is bounded frome above, then $A$ is too.

Comment: @KittyL The title is not well defined, I meant the intersection of $A$ and $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @gbox: What I gave is the intersection of $A$ and $\mathbb{Z}$. You meant @dtldarek?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A \subset \mathbb R$ bounded from above implies that $A \cap \mathbb Z$ is bounded from above, but the other direction is false in general. Just think about an unbounded set consisting of non-integer elements, then $A \cap \mathbb Z = \emptyset$ is bounded.

Your proof for the implication "$A$ bounded from above $\Rightarrow$ $A \cap \mathbb Z$ bounded from above" is a bit complicated and missing some parts: Why is the intersection $A \cap \mathbb Z$ finite, why are finite sets bounded from above?

A more formal proof is the following: Assume that $A$ is bounded from above, i.e. there exists $C \in \mathbb R$ such that $a < C$ for all $a \in A$. The same constant is a bound for $A \cap \mathbb Z$: Let $a \in A \cap \mathbb Z$, i.e. $a \in A$ and $a \in \mathbb Z$. Because $a \in A$ we can conclude $a < C$.

The proof shows that it doesn't matter what we intersect the set with, i.e. your generalized statement is true.

Comment: so it is not true that the claim is $\iff$ it is just $\rightarrow$?

Comment: Yes, just that implication is true.